# AEM 6.5 - Display thumbnails in Sites directory

Tags: aem

I'm having troubles generating thumbnails for AEM sites.

[image: AEM sites]

But I don't have any clue why after generating thumbnails in each page properties and saving them, the thumbnails still broken.

In page properties looks like this:

[image: Page properties]

I posted this question if anybody is having the same issue. Maybe it's missing any configuration or any file in the CRXDE I overlooked... 
Thanks,

Comment: how did you add Thumbnails? is it part of Template or you added via page properties? Lastly, Have you checked We-retail sample implementation?

Comment: On page properties I tried generating thumbnails or by selecting images from the damAdmin. Yes, in a clean AEM instance with We-retail sample implementation works fine but I haven't found differences compared against project instance so far..